# The Info window top part is not revealing the full numbers I need to see about polycount

Tags: modeling, polycount

Hey I just wanna see how many polygons or triangles a specific mesh has. I guess going into edit mode should allow this. Btw, some high-poly meshes, I don't really want to go into edit mode, cause it can be slow. So.

1) Is there a way to see the polycount for a specific mesh in the scene, and not go into edit mode?

2) Why do I get this partially hidden by the three dots ... polycount info?

Thx!

[image]

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time.

Comment: 1) - Go into *Local View* with said object selected by pressing `Numpad /`